# Java- difference between String object and user defined objects

Tags: java, object

This is a simple java program. It contains a class "Student" and we are making its two objects stud,stud1. Similarly I have also made a String object "a" whose value is "Hello".

```
class Student{

  int age;

  public void setAge(int age){
    this.age=age;
  }

  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }
}


class Hello{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    Student stud= new Student();
    Student stud1= new Student();
    stud.setAge(15);
    int i=stud.getAge();
    String a=new String("Hello");
    System.out.println(stud);
    System.out.println(stud1);
    System.out.println(a);
  }

}
```

As we know when we create a class object, it just holds a reference values for that object.That's why when I tried to print stud and stud1 I am getting two reference values.But since "a" is an object of class String we should expect a reference value instead of value "Hello".Why its happening?

Comment: Please note that "Hello" is already a String, thus the new String() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
System.out.println(stud);
```

is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to

```
System.out.println(stud.toString());
```

Since `String` [overrides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) the [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method you get something more meaningful than a bunch of characters and digits when printing strings.

You could let your user-defined classes do this too. In your `Student` class it would look like this:

```
class Student{

    int age;

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age=age;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {              // Called for instance when
        return "Student with age " + age;   // the student should be printed
    }
}
```

Here's an [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/5NLmB) for a run with your code where `Student` overrides `toString`.

**Further reading:**

- Documentation for [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) (the fall-back method for classes that do *not* override it)
- Documentation for [`PrintStream.println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [Implementing toString](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55)

<sup>1) Unless stud equals null</sup>

Comment: Perhaps you can do this by implementing as such: return "My age is: "+age;

Comment: In fact, not `stud.toString()`, but `Straing.valueOf(stud)`, that for not null objects calls `stud.toString()`

Answer (score 4):

When you call `System.out.println(x)`, the String output is the `.toString()` of the object passed to it.

Of course the `.toString()` of a `String` is the string itself, so you'd expect `"Hello"`.

If your class doesn't define a `.toString()` method (and it doesn't), the `.toString()` defined for its parent (is the `Object` class) is used, which prints a value based on type/class and the `hashCode()` of the object.

Answer (score 1):

When you hand System.out.println() an object, it will call that object's toString() method in order to be able to print something out. Object has a default toString() method, and that's what's getting called for your Student objects, because you did not override the toString() method. Strings, however, have toString() defined in the obvious way, so it's printing out that custom string representation of the object; namely, the value of the string.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `System.out.println(Object)` , the `toString()` method of that object is called. Since you dont have one implemented for `Student`, the `Object.toString()` is called which prints the reference value.

To print meaningful values, override it like so --

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Age = " + age;
}
```

Comment: Won't even compile I'm afraid. You need to return a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()`method of a is called and prints the String "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

Your student class just don't override toString() method, which is inherited by every java object:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Answer (score 0):

Simply, there is `println(Object obj)` method inside the `PrintStream` class (System.out is an instance of PrintStream), and inside its implementation there is `obj.toString()`. You can override `toString()` of any object to format the string yields from calling `System.out.println(Object obj)`.